# Why do the pixels have different sizes, when I try to display pixel-art in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I like pixel-art games, and it's also the only kind of art I can kind of do myself. So I like to make my games in pixel-art too. The problem I have with that is that the pixels when displayed in Phaser don't have the same sizes anymore.

My issue becomes very obvious with the images:

[image]
[image]

The first picture is what it looks like in Phaser and the second image is what it's supposed to look like. As you can see the spots on the mushroom in Phaser have different sizes, even though they're supposed to be just one pixel with the same size. I don't understand this at all, and I can't find anything on the internet about it. I tried all different possibilities with scaling or no scaling and changing the game size, but nothing seems to fix it. This happened in every game I've made. There's no point in showing a specific example of a game, but I can show the game config

```
var config = {
width: 768,
height: 448,
pixelArt: true,
scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH
},
scene: [BootScene, StartScene, MainScene, InventoryScene, InstructionsScene],
physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade:{
        //debug: true,
        gravity: {y: 980}
    }
}
```

}

I can only imagine it has something to do with my config. Because I add the images as normal sprites/images in Phaser. This perticualt spriteis animated, but other images (and text too btw) that aren't animated share the same problem. This image also has scale 2, but as I mentioned changing the scale doesn't help.

Does anybode have any idea what's causing this? Maybe I'm just overlooking something totally obvious, but this has been bothering me for months now and I just can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: You need to make sure, in your viewport size, scaling etc., that 1 pixel in the sprite corresponds to a whole number of pixels on the screen. Not, for example, 3.5 pixels, because then you get this problem of alternatingly 3 and 4 screen pixels per sprite pixel.

Comment: I think I get what you mean and I can see that in my tiles for example, one pixel equals to 3 screen pixels and then another pixel equals to 4 screen pixels. But my question is how do I prevent this?

Comment: This might help: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/36607-scaling-the-canvas-for-pixel-art/ , if you don't have the solution you can just use the zoom property of phaser config to descale your pixel art. It will apply on all your assets.